# what if conditional expression might not exist?

Tags: python

is there a better/shorter/more normal way of doing this:

```
try: 
    sys.argv[1]
except:
    mod.init()
else:
    mod.init("y") if sys.argv[1]=="y" else mod.init()
```

I soon discovered *function if else* doesn't work if argv[1] doesn't exist.

Comment: `if sys.argv[1:] and sys.argv[1] == "y": mod.init("y")   else: mod.init()` might be somewhat clearer.

Comment: I would be nice if you could write `sys.argv.get(1)`, like with `dict` values. But I would define a variable like `arg` first, *then* unconditionally call `mod.init(arg)`.

Comment: I'd also strongly consider using `argparse` to handle retrieving the argument. It can make it easier to ensure that whatever value you get is either `"y"` or the appropriate default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `argparse`, and make sure the default value of the command line argument  is whatever the default value of `mod.init`'s parameter is. You can make the argument optional and restrict it to a value of `y`.

When you run the script, you'll get an error if anything *other* than `y` is used for the option positional argument, so if `mod.init` is called at all, it will only be called with `"y"` or `None` as its argument.

```
import argparse


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("init_arg", choices=["y"], nargs='?', default=None)
args = p.parse_args()

mod.init(args.init_arg)
```